Event receiver not firing on Tasks list
SharePoint 2010 style SPD workflow is running on a list. All tasks are inserted into Tasks list.
I created ItemAdding event receiver on Tasks list but it never fires when a new task is assigned. I created ItemAdding event receiver on a custom list and it works fine.
What could be the reason it is not firing event on Tasks list?
